# Regex Protection(Bypassing to XSS or Open Redirect) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, redirect, xss

Anyone in the universe can help me finding out the function.What will be done with this regex string

```
/^#~?!(?:\/?[\w\.-])+\/?(?:\?|$)/
```

When it passed to this javascript statement like this.

```
(/^#~?!(?:\/?[\w\.-])+\/?(?:\?|$)/).test(location.hash)&&location.replace(location.hash.substr(location.hash.indexOf('!')+1));
```

And is it possible to bypass this regex string may be making an xss attack or an open redirect?

**EDIT :-**

Ok iam going more accurate.
My goal is to break the above **Regex Match** to make an xss or open redirect.(Only for education purpose,like a CrackMe).

So For Eg:-
If i used `#!stackoverflow.com` then the browser redirects to current domain plus stackoverflow.com
Like

> domain.com/foo/#!stackoverflow.com

it redirects to `domain.com/stackoverflow.com`.

So i tried putting like this `#!//stackoverflow.com` but the regex match fails.

Is there anyway to bypass it to make an open redirect to stackoverflow.com(Any kinda character encodings or anything else).

If else is it possible to make an XSS in this current context.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

it must :

- start with # (a hash in a url)
- then maybe a "~" (one or zero)
- then "!"
- then one ore more letters (\w ) or dots (.) or dash (-)
- then maybe a "slash" (one or zero)
- then a "?" or then end of the string

This means it matches url like

```
http://yourdomain/foo/#!bar?etc
```

and replace the current url with

```
http://yourdomain/foo/bar?etc
```

to try to access directly the file "bar" if it exists

The risk is if your site is in ajax, and you make somewhere a direct and blind include() of what is in the hash.

Comment: Hello Sly,As you have said may be the URL can look like that after the # sign.But i need to know is there anyway to bypass the protection or may be passing the regex test and making the redirect an open redirect or by altering the content to make a XSS.Is it possible.

Comment: Hello Shihab
Not enough information about how your site works... You want to know if it could be possible to call an adress with a hash without being replaced by the regexp ?

Comment: slashes (before the end of the string) and colon dont match so I don't think you can go outside the domain... (http://regex101.com/r/rE5pK6/1 )

Comment: So are you saying.It is impossible to bypass.And is there any kinda encoding or anything that can result to an XSS.

Comment: I did'nt find a way to inject any encoded special character (but I'm not an expert, and would be very interested ton know if someone has a "solution"...)

Comment: Ya may be someone from the space :).Iam also trying different payloads but at last i have closely encoutered...